Is there a lower energy state of carbon than carbon dioxide?
This question came to my mind when I was reading an article https://www.project-syndicate.org/commentary/illusion-of-soil-carbon-offsets-by-sophie-scherger-2024-11 related to carbon sequestration and climate change. If we burn fossil fuel and release carbon in the form of carbon dioxide, why can't we recapture them in a lower energy chemical form?

There certainly are ways to react CO2 exothermically. A number of basic oxides can do, but you need to make them. Fortunately there's some natural minerals which work well enough.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135261/whats-the-minimum-amount-of-energy-needed-to-remove-co2-from-the-atmosphere https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115799/how-to-capture-the-gas-produced-by-combusting-alcohols

Well, looks like guys were keen on answering, so maybe tell us what "lower energy state of carbon" is supposed to be.

The greatest oxidation number of carbon is $+4$ and it occurs in molecules like $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{H2CO3}$ and carbonates or bicarbonates. It is easy to transform any such structure into any of the three other ones. But it is not possible to transform them into some other ones having a lower energy.

Thank you for providing a scientific explantion to my economic observation of "no free lunch" in this case!

If you want to sequester carbon dioxide, you either have to enclose it (because it is a gas at ambient temperature and pressure), find a way to bind it to something else, or react it with something else to store it as solid or liquid.
The combination of two oxygen atoms for every carbon atom is most stable as carbon dioxide.
